# Cannot retrieve rows from .NET OleDB.DataReader

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access, oledb

i have a problem with a SQL Statement.

My environment is as follows:

- VB.NET application that queries a MS Access (2002) through the .NET OleDB.DataReader

That query doesn't deliver any rows/results. But when i execute the query on the MS Access database it delivers the correct result.

The query is:

```
<i>select prnr.prk, prnr.prl, famk, faml from 
(fzgpr inner join prnr on prnr.id = fzgpr.prid) 
inner join prfamilie on prfamilie.id = prnr.famid 
where ((fzgpr.fzgid) = 1) and ((FamL) like '*Air*')</i>
```

I tried different brackets, but none worked. I noticed, that removing the second part of the where clause (and ((FamL)...) solves that issue, but i need that second part!!

I can't find the error, please help me,...

Comment: you should try replacing '*' with '%' when selecting though oledb

Comment: Good news is that your database side is working ;) and the work is to get your .net to make them talk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say if you are running a query through OleDB, you have to conform to more SQL based syntax and use `((FamL) like '%Air%')`

I run a few applications off Access Databases (mine are all 2010) and that is the syntax that I use.  I also use OleDB for all read access to the database.